# on GNU C compilation for creating obj files

Tags: debugging, dwarf, object-files

What is full form of DWARF as i have seen that in objdump analysis, Learning the DWARF debug information format.
I have tried analyzing a simple program

```
void main()
{
    printf("Hello World!!\n");
}
```

I wanted to analyse how this could be in instructions as in .o files?
Please can anyone help?

I wanted to map my program with (objdump -d file.o) too,

```
00000000 main:

   0:   55                      push   %ebp

   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp

   3:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp

   6:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp

   9:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax

   e:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)

  11:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   12 <main+0x12>

  16:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax

  1b:   c9                      leave  

  1c:   c3                      ret
```

Answer (score 1):

DWARF: Debug With Arbitrary Record Format.  Get more information [here](http://dwarfstd.org/doc/Debugging%20using%20DWARF-2012.pdf).